# What is the max attack speed you can get?

Tags: league-of-legends

I often see people going double phantom dancers which has lead me to ask.

Can you go full out attack speed? Is there a limit to attack speed?

Answer (score 5):

2.5 Attack Speed (2.5 basic attacks per second) is the maximum for any game mode.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_Speed)

Comment: Good, quick and right =)